# Problem Installing Ubuntu from USB live stick on Lenovo T410

Tags: usb

I have Ubuntu on my Lenovo T410 and it recently stopped working.

When I load with the usb stick, it shows a screen saying 'GNU GRUB version 2.02' and then 'Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)'.

I cannot load a new Ubuntu operating system via the usb stick.

The stick was created on an old macbook.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Redo the USB because that one has errors.

Comment: have a T410 too ;) - Your usb stick or usb port is the source of the issue. First try another usb port, second try to rebuild the usb stick